# SpringAOP introductions with AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm new in SpringAOP. I want to write simple example of **Introductions** but can't understand clearly how it must work.

In documentation I find that:

*[Introduction: declaring additional methods or fields on behalf of a type. Spring AOP allows you to introduce new interfaces (and a corresponding implementation) to any advised object. For example, you could use an introduction to make a bean implement an IsModified interface, to simplify caching. (An introduction is known as an inter-type declaration in the AspectJ community.)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html)*

And I write simple example:
I write simple class with one method

```
public class Test {
    public void test1(){
        System.out.println("Test1");
    }
}
```

Then I write interface and class that implements this interface

```
public interface ITest2 {
    void test2();
}

public class Test2Impl implements ITest2{
    @Override
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("Test2");
    }
}
```

and finally my aspect

```
@Aspect
public class AspectClass {

    @DeclareParents(
            value = "by.bulgak.test.Test+",
            defaultImpl = Test2Impl.class
    )
    public static ITest2 test2;
}
```

my spring configuration file look like this:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<bean id="aspect" class="by.bulgak.aspect.AspectClass" />
```

So my question:
How can I you this now. what I need to write in my main class to sea result?
May be I need to write some other classes.(book in which I read about SpringAOP I can't find full examples)

**UPDATE**

My main method looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-configuration.xml");
    Test test = (Test) appContext.getBean("test");
    test.test1();
    ITest2 test2 = (ITest2) appContext.getBean("test");
    test2.test2();

}
```

When I execute my app i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5 cannot be cast to by.bulgak.test.Test
```

at this line:

```
Test test = (Test) appContext.getBean("test");
```

Comment: Show me your `Test` bean declaration in your configuration file.

Comment: @RohitJain `<bean id="test" class="by.bulgak.test.Test"/>`

Comment: @RohitJain but project works fine I I comment this two lines:`Test test = (Test) appContext.getBean("test");
    test.test1();`

Comment: Ah! There's the problem. You need to define an interface `Test1`, and make class `Test` implement that. And then change the typecast to `Test1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to define the bean `Test` in your configuration file:

```
<bean id="test" class="Test" />
```

Then in main, get this bean from `ApplicationContext`:

```
Test test1 = (Test) context.getBean("test");
```

Now, from `test1` reference, you can only invoke method defined in `Test` bean. To use the newly introduced behaviour, you need to typecast the reference to the interface containing that behaviour:

```
ITest2 test2 = (ITest2) context.getBean("test");
```

Then, you can access the method of `Test2` from this reference:

```
test2.test2();
```

This will invoke the method defined in the bean as specified in the `defaultImpl` attribute of `@DeclareParents` annotation.

Comment: when I start app I get such error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5 cannot be cast to by.bulgak.test.Test`

Comment: Where are you getting that exception?