# SpringAOP introductions with AspectJ using Annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-aop

I am learning **Introductions** (known as inter-type declarations in AspectJ). I got an example from [SpringAOP introductions with AspectJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176169/springaop-introductions-with-aspectj]) using xml. **I am trying to replicate the same using annotations**, but I don't know how to proceed. I did a lot of research in internet but could not find any samples. Could you please help me with this.

**PerformanceTest.class**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ConcertConfig.class)
public class PerformanceTest {

    @Autowired
    public Audience audience;

    @Autowired
    public Performance liveOpera;

    @Autowired
    public EncoreableIntroducer encoreable;

    @Test
    public void testPerformance(){
        liveOpera.perform();
    }
}
```

**LiveOpera.class**

```
public class LiveOpera implements Performance{
    @Override
    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("Live Opera Performance Started");   
    }}
```

**Encoreable.interface**

```
public interface Encoreable {
    public void performEncore();
}
```

**DefaultEncoreable.class**

```
public class DefaultEncoreable implements Encoreable {
    @Override
    public void performEncore() {
        System.out.println("WoW!! What an encore performance!!");
    }
}
```

**ConcertConfig.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan
public class ConcertConfig {

    @Bean
    public Audience audience(){
        return new Audience();
    }

    @Bean
    public LiveOpera opera(){
        return new LiveOpera();
    }

    @Bean
    public EncoreableIntroducer encoreable(){
        return new EncoreableIntroducer();
    }

}
```

**Performance Interface**

```
public interface Performance {
    public void perform();
}
```

**EncoreableIntroducer.class**

```
@Aspect
public class EncoreableIntroducer {
    @DeclareParents(value="com.example.introduction.Performance+",
            defaultImpl=DefaultEncoreable.class)
    public static Encoreable encoreable;
}
```

**Audience.class**

```
@Aspect
public class Audience {

    @Pointcut("execution(** com.example.introduction.Performance.perform(..))")
    public void performance() {
    }

    public void silenceMobilePhones() {
        System.out.println("Silencing Mobile Phones");
    }

    public void takeSeats() {
        System.out.println("Taking seats");
    }

    public void applause() {
        System.out.println("CLAP CLAP CLAP!!");
    }

    public void demandRefund() {
        System.out.println("Need a Refund!!");
    }

    @Around("performance()")
    public void wrapPerformance(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) {
        try {
            silenceMobilePhones();
            takeSeats();
            jp.proceed();
            applause();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            demandRefund();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output: When Executing @Test method in PerformanceTest.class**

```
Silencing Mobile Phones
Taking seats
Live Opera Performance Started
CLAP CLAP CLAP!!
```

**Please let me know, How can I use the aspect in EncoreableIntroducer.class using AspectJ-Introductions, so that could use the perform() method in DefaultEncoreable.class?**

**Expecteing the Output like below on using AspectJ Introductions:**

```
Silencing Mobile Phones
Taking seats
WoW!! What an encore performance!!
Live Opera Performance Started
CLAP CLAP CLAP!!
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn how to ask questions here by presenting the code you have already and describing which problem you have with it. This is no "build my complete code to order for free" platform. I am sure everyone would appreciate an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of just a link and a "do it for me completely" request. So please edit your question.

Comment: @kriegaex I have updated the question as per your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having several problems here:

- You are working with two interfaces (`Performance` vs. `Encoreable`) implementing the same methods. Why?
- You are trying to introduce a method to `LiveOpera` which it already has, namely `void perform()`. Probably your intention is to override the original one. This will neither work in Spring AOP nor in AspectJ. You can only introduce methods which do not exist in the target class yet.
- You are trying to intercept a method introduced by aspect A in another aspect B. This only works in AspectJ, not in Spring AOP, as far as I know. I am not a Spring user, but quickly gave it a try and it does not work. When replicating your situation in AspectJ, it worked. So what you could do is activate [AspectJ via LTW](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) in your Spring application and modify your code to make it work, avoiding the first two problems I described.

---

#### Update and answer to question asked in comment:

First of all I got rid of your manual `@Bean` methods in the configuration class because you had enabled component scan anyway. Instead, I just added `@Component` annotations to the `LiveOpera` class and the two aspects. Your method also works, but I like this better:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan
public class ConcertConfig {}
```

Looks cleaner, doesn't it? Just don't forget the `@Component` annotations where they belong.

Now, the real solution. In the aspect, change your advice to:

```java
@Around("performance() && this(encoreable)")
public void wrapPerformance(ProceedingJoinPoint jp, Encoreable encoreable) {
  try {
    silenceMobilePhones();
    takeSeats();
    encoreable.performEncore();
    jp.proceed();
    applause();
  } catch (Throwable e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    e.printStackTrace();
    demandRefund();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! I have changed the method perform() to performEncore() in the Encoreable interface. I want to use/call this newly introduced method in PerformanceTest using aspect. Could you please tell me how can I achieve this?